# Which Modernizr feature is reponsible for browser detection?

Tags: jquery, modernizr

Sorry it is my first time using Modernizr.

I have a legacy code that I need to rewrite `(If its NOT ie or its IE > 6)`

```
if(!$.browser.msie || ($.browser.msie&&$.browser.version>6)){
}
```

1) After some research I could use this for the second part of the condition. However how do I check for if its NOT ie?

```
if ($('body').is('.gt-ie6 *')) {
  // IE10, 9, 8, 7, ...
}
```

2) Looking at http://modernizr.com/download/  what do I have to tick to include the check above in the library?

Many Thanks

Comment: Modernizr is not meant to do browser detection, it's feature detection. Best practice denote that you shouldn't care what browser it is, but what features are supported.

Of course, some situations like your's might just require legacy code. Can you provide an example of what code you MUST have for IE? There might be a solution with modernizr or some way to gracefully degrade it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain if I understand your question correctly, but if the test is:

if (not IE) or if (IE > 6) do this

then why not turn it around? If you code above is correct, then maybe something similar to

```
if ($('body').not('.ie6 *')) {
// everything except ie6
do this
}
```